# What are the options available for plotting graphs from a table? (Without using any plotting library )

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

What are the options available for plotting graphs upon selecting different columns from a Data Table. I have worked with ag-grid and I want some thing like that which will come directly out of the box without using any other graph library(like plotly or highcharts) and manually writing code.

Comment: Canvas would be your best bed. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API)

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment, I recommend looking into `Canvas` ([mdn](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API)).

Here's a minimal exmaple that allows panning (mouse 1) and zooming (mouse 2) in addition to callbacks for clicks and mouse moves.

```js
class Chart {
 constructor(canvas, hoverCallback, clickCallback) {
  this.width = canvas.width;
  this.height = canvas.height;
  this.ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  this.ctx.font = '14px serif';
  canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
   this.dragged = false;
   this.mouseDown = {x: e.offsetX, y: e.offsetY};
  });
  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
   hoverCallback?.(this.pixelToCoord(e.offsetX, e.offsetY));
   if (!this.mouseDown)
    return;
   this.dragged = true;
   if (e.buttons & 1 && !e.shiftKey)
    this.panRange(e.offsetX - this.mouseDown.x, e.offsetY - this.mouseDown.y);
   else if (e.buttons & 2 || e.shiftKey)
    this.zoomRange(e.offsetX - this.mouseDown.x, e.offsetY - this.mouseDown.y);
   this.mouseDown = {x: e.offsetX, y: e.offsetY};
  });
  canvas.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => hoverCallback?.());
  document.addEventListener('mouseup', () => this.mouseDown = null);
  canvas.addEventListener('click', e => {
   if (this.dragged)
    return;
   clickCallback?.(this.pixelToCoord(e.offsetX, e.offsetY));
  });
  canvas.addEventListener('dblclick', e => {
   if (this.dragged)
    return;
   this.resetRange(e.shiftKey);
  });
  this.pointSets = [];
  this.resetRange();
 }

 set pointSets(value) {
  this.pointSets_ = value;
  this.draw();
 }

 resetRange(zeroMins = false) {
  let allPoints = this.pointSets_
   .flatMap(({points}) => points);
  [this.minX, this.deltaX] = Chart.getRange(allPoints.map(({x}) => x), zeroMins);
  [this.minY, this.deltaY] = Chart.getRange(allPoints.map(({y}) => y), zeroMins);
  this.verifyRange();
  this.draw();
 }

 panRange(x, y) {
  this.minX -= x * this.deltaX / this.width;
  this.minY += y * this.deltaY / this.height;
  this.verifyRange();
  this.draw();
 }

 zoomRange(x, y) {
  let dx = x * this.deltaX / this.width;
  let dy = -y * this.deltaY / this.height;
  this.minX += dx;
  this.minY += dy;
  this.deltaX -= dx * 2;
  this.deltaY -= dy * 2;
  this.verifyRange();
  this.draw();
 }

 verifyRange() {
  this.minX = Math.max(this.minX, -this.deltaX / 10);
  this.minY = Math.max(this.minY, -this.deltaY / 10);
 }

 draw() {
  if (!this.pointSets_ || this.minX === undefined)
   return;
  this.ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
  this.ctx.fillRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
  this.drawPoints();
  this.drawAxis();
 }

 drawPoints() {
  this.pointSets_.forEach(({color, fill, size, points, isPath}) => {
   this.ctx.strokeStyle = color;
   this.ctx.fillStyle = color;
   if (isPath) {
    this.ctx.lineWidth = size;
    this.ctx.beginPath();
    points.forEach((p, i) => {
     let {x, y} = this.coordToPixel(p.x, p.y);
     if (!i)
      this.ctx.moveTo(x, y);
     else
      this.ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    });
    if (fill)
     this.ctx.fill();
    else
     this.ctx.stroke();
   } else {
    points.forEach(p => {
     let {x, y} = this.coordToPixel(p.x, p.y);
     this.ctx[fill ? 'fillRect' : 'strokeRect'](x - size / 2, y - size / 2, size, size);
    });
   }
  });
 }

 drawAxis() {
  let n = 20;
  let step = this.width / n;
  let size = 10;
  let sizeSmall = 1;

  this.ctx.lineWidth = 1;
  this.ctx.strokeStyle = `rgb(0, 0, 0)`;
  this.ctx.fillStyle = `rgb(0, 0, 0)`;
  this.ctx.strokeRect(this.width / n, this.height * (n - 1) / n, this.width * (n - 2) / n, 0); // x axis line
  this.ctx.strokeRect(this.width / n, this.height / n, 0, this.width * (n - 2) / n); // y axis line
  for (let i = 2; i < n; i += 2) {
   let x = i * step;
   let y = (n - i) * step;
   let xText = Chart.numToPrint(this.minX + i / n * this.deltaX);
   let yText = Chart.numToPrint(this.minY + i / n * this.deltaY);
   this.ctx.fillText(xText, x - 9, step * (n - 1) + 17); // x axis text
   this.ctx.fillText(yText, step - 28, y + 4, 30); // y axis text
   this.ctx.fillRect(x - sizeSmall / 2, step * (n - 1) - size / 2, sizeSmall, size); // x axis dots
   this.ctx.fillRect(step - size / 2, x - sizeSmall / 2, size, sizeSmall); // y axis dots
  }
 }

 pixelToCoord(x, y) {
  return {
   x: x / this.width * this.deltaX + this.minX,
   y: (1 - y / this.height) * this.deltaY + this.minY,
   width: 20 / this.width * this.deltaX,
   height: 20 / this.height * this.deltaY
  };
 }

 coordToPixel(x, y) {
  return {
   x: x === Infinity ? this.width : (x - this.minX) / this.deltaX * this.width,
   y: y === Infinity ? 0 : (1 - (y - this.minY) / this.deltaY) * this.height,
  };
 }

 static getRange(values, zeroMin = false, buffer = .1) {
  let min = values.length && !zeroMin ? Math.min(...values) : 0;
  let max = values.length ? Math.max(...values) : 10;
  let delta = max - min + .001;
  return [min - delta * buffer, delta + delta * buffer * 2]
 }

 static numToPrint(n) {
  return Math.round(n * 10) / 10;
 }
}

let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
let chart = new Chart(canvas);

chart.pointSets = [
 // e.g. {color: 'rgb(255,0,0)', fill: true, size: 5, points: [{x: 0, y: 1}, ...], isPath: true}
 {
  color: 'rgb(255,0,0)',
  fill: false,
  size: 3,
  points: [
   {x: 0, y: 1},
   {x: 1, y: 1},
   {x: 1, y: 0},
   {x: 0, y: 0},
   {x: 0, y: .5},
  ],
  isPath: true,
 }, {
  color: 'rgb(0,0,255)',
  fill: true,
  size: 10,
  points: [
   {x: 0, y: 1},
   {x: 0, y: .5},
   {x: 3, y: 1},
   {x: 6, y: 2},
   {x: 7, y: 4},
   {x: 6, y: 5},
  ],
  isPath: false,
 },
];
chart.resetRange();
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<canvas width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```